# Would running NPC AI scripts be a good use case for web workers?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I currently have a game with about 1500 non player characters all of which at the moment are running some variation of an AI script.  Right now this AI is really simple.  NPC's simply walk from location to location randomly.  This all happens in a game loop currently timed at 3 seconds as the game plays out in 3 second intervals.

Right now my AI doesn't seem to lock up the UI, but I imagine with more complexity or even more NPC's that it likely will start causing hiccups in the UI.  Is this a good use case for web workers?  My initial research tells me that I shouldn't create too many web workers so similar AI would likely be pooled together in a web worker of there own.

For anyone interested in actually looking at code this code would give you a good idea of what I'm doing although much of it has been rewritten at this time.  https://github.com/caimen/subfaction

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code review service. There is a related [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) that might be of interested. In any case, the best way to find out the answer here is to push your system to an extreme case where it breaks, then figure out if that's acceptable. For example if you're expecting ~1.5K characters and it still runs fine with 50K even with much more complicated logic then it's a non-issue. **Premature optimization** will eat you alive if you're not careful.

Comment: I tried to ask the question in a way that it could have a non-opinion based answer.  I still believe the title question can can be answered in a way that would be based on fact and not opinion.  I'm aware of stack overflow's policies and unless you can provide a good reason why I don't believe this question should be closed as primarily opinion based.  I'm not looking for code review, I'm looking for fact based evidence why or why not this is not a good use case for web workers.  If you believe this question is not suitable for stack overflow, please specify why.

Comment: It's still largely a matter of opinion. This is an architectural consideration and there are many possible solutions, too many to enumerate here. Look at how conventional MUD-type games implemented this with a simple event loop and branch out from there.

Comment: I actually began learning how to program on Merc based GodWars MUDs.    Pretty much every DIKU/Merc based MUD runs on a similar game loop.  The considerations are a bit different with a single player browser based game with an actual user interface.  The main concern is locking up the user interface with the main game loop and whether or not web workers could be used to mitigate that.

Comment: Testing, testing, testing. This is how you find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some tests and web workers do seem like a good use case for large amounts of NPC AI.  You can indeed make changes to the DOM with lot's of processing going on the background with web workers.  Not only that but they really are threads and actually do utilize processor cores at least in Chrome.  There are other considerations such as how many web workers to actually spawn, for that I found a nifty core estimator https://github.com/oftn-oswg/core-estimator

There is an excellent tool that is probably a bit out of date but still works.  It can benchmark about how many web workers is ideal for your computer and gives an interesting idea about there power.

http://pmav.eu/stuff/javascript-webworkers/

Of course if your AI is fairly simple and you aren't experiencing lag in the DOM there really is no need to overkill with this.